# Signing with comodo pfx in Installshield Fails when build executed through commandline

Tags: installshield, pfx

I have updated a new comodo CodeSign certificate by modifying the pfx and password in the ISM file ,

Now when running the build through the installshield IDE i see the package is signed successfully :

```
Successfully signed: 2070.mst
Started signing 1048.mst ...
Successfully signed: 1048.mst
```

While executing the same ISM file using IsCmdBld.exe through the command line i get :

```
[exec] Started signing 2070.mst ...
[exec] Number of errors: 1
[exec] SignTool Error: The specified PFX password is not correct.
[exec] ISDEV : error -1027: Failed signing 2070.mst
[exec] Started signing 1048.mst ...
[exec] Number of errors: 1
[exec] SignTool Error: The specified PFX password is not correct.
[exec] ISDEV : error -1027: Failed signing 1048.mst
```

Comment: Are these on the same machine and in the same context? The `[exec]` in the iscmdbld.exe output indicates it's being run by another tool, perhaps system context? If these could be on machines with different language settings, does the password contain any characters that are not ASCII compatible? What version of InstallShield? (2015's log would look different.)

Comment: Same machine , the [exec] is because its from a CC.NET log , though behind the scenes CC.NET runs on the same machine and all it does is running a commandline , i`m using installshield 2010